# Office.js displayDialogAsync not available

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm using office.js to open dialogbox and login user.

When I run `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()` I get `undefined` error

I have inspected the content of `Office.context.ui` this is what I got:

**[image: strong text]**

It's missing `displayDialogAsync()` method

Some days ago it was working

I'm using this version : https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js

Comment: Can you please confirm which platform you are using: Outlook Web, Mac or Windows?

Comment: I have tried with web and  mac and I get the same issue

Comment: I have found the issue, I was calling  displayDialogAsync() inside the dialogAPI box , that's why the method was not available.